# What does SCC stand for, with respect to LLVM?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I was reading through this document http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html, where in I came across [CallGraphSCCPass](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CallGraphSCCPass.html). I searched for SCC abbreviation, but wasn't able to find one. What does SCC stand for? Where can I read more about it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to [The LLVM Lexicon](http://llvm.org/docs/Lexicon.html#SCC), It stands for "[strongly connected component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component)".

The source-code comments explain it this way:

> Because there may be cycles in the call graph, passes of this type operate on the call-graph in SCC order: that is, they process function bottom-up, except for recursive functions, which they process all at once.

(But the only reason I was able to find the lexicon is that I figured out that they must mean "strongly connected component", and then I Googled for that phrase on `site:llvm.org` to confirm. It doesn't seem to be prominently linked.)

Comment: To my understanding, they actually contract SCCs into single vertices, and the graphs become a DAG, which could be bottom-up passed. Is it correct?

Comment: @zsf222: Yes, that's my understanding.

Comment: Accidentally, SCC also stands for 'source code comments'...

Answer (score 7):

I believe it stands for [Strongly Connected Components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_components), since that documentation talks about [Tarjan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm).

Answer (score 2):

SCC = Strongly connected component